# How to convert sql-timestamp to string in Racket?

Tags: lisp, timestamp, scheme, racket

The closest thing I came up with looking at the documentation was

```
(define (sql-datetime->rfc2822 datetime)
  (let ([dt (sql-datetime->srfi-date datetime)])
    (date->string dt (date-display-format 'rfc2822))))
```

But it fails when I pass it a `sql-timestamp`

```
> (sql-datetime->rfc2822 st)
. . date->string: contract violation
 expected: date?
 given: (tm:date 456232000 10 39 18 5 5 2013 0)
in: the 1st argument of
      (->* (date?) (any/c) string?)
contract from: <collects>/racket/date.rkt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Racket version 5.3.4, you need to use the `date->string` function from the `srfi/19` library because the structure types for `racket/date` and `srfi/19` are incompatible (in 5.3.4, which will be released soon, they use the same structure). It should work if you `(require srfi/19)` and use the API defined there.